# How to find a file on the $PATH in Bash?

Tags: bash, path, posix

The utility `which` will find a *program* on the path but what about an arbitrary data file?

I must be searching for the wrong stuff but I can't find any way to do this with a standard utility so I thought of writing a little Bash script to do it.

The `$PATH` environment variable is separated by colons, but trying to set `IFS=':'` and then iterate over the results is not working for me. Here's what I've got so far:

```
IFS=':' DIRS=($PATH)
for d in $DIRS; do echo $d; done
```

At this point it only outputs the first entry in my path rather than all of them.

Thoughts? If there's already a standard command that does this then there's no reason to write a script ...

Comment: Arbitrary data files probably shouldn't be in directories lists in `PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few of things going on here:

1. <strike>`IFS=':' DIRS=($PATH)`</strike>

   bash will expand the variable *before* setting IFS and DIRS, so it's too late by then.
   You'll need something crazy like

   ```
   dirs=()
   while IFS= read -r -d: dir || [ "$dir" ]; do dirs+=("$dir"); done <<<"$PATH"
   ```

-- nope, that was wrong. First the $PATH variable is expanded, then IFS is set, then the DIRS element is split using IFS because it is unquoted.

1. `for d in $DIRS; do echo $d; done`

   To iterate over all the elements of an array, you need

   ```
   for d in "${dirs[@]}" ...
   ```

   With an array, `$DIRS` is equal to `${DIRS[0]}`, i.e. the first entry.
2. Don't use ALLCAPS varnames. It's too easy to overwrite a crucial system variable.
3. [Quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) unless you know *exactly* what will happen if you don't.

Answer (score 11):

Using this, using bash *parameter expansions* and `find`:

```
find ${PATH//:/\/ } -name 'file'
```

Comment: Suppose there's a directory in the PATH that has a space in it. Or a file in a directory in the PATH with a space in the filename.

Comment: You're also not expanding the files in the *last* PATH entry.

Comment: This solution would be great if I could use `find` in a way that searches the `$PATH` but replacing colons with spaces isn't going to work

Comment: @GillesQuenot I've upvoted your `find` solution because I like it _but_ it won't work when there's spaces in directories that are in `$PATH`

Comment: I never use spaces especially for a PATH directory, and I like my solution too ^^

Comment: If you do have spaces in your `$PATH` but have managed to split the entries into an array, simply use `find "${array[@]}" -name "$file"`

Answer (score 5):

The error is not with the assignment, but with not looping over the array.

```
IFS=: dirs=($PATH)
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    echo "$dir"
done
```

works for me; or more succinctly

```
printf '%s\n' "${dirs[@]}"
```

Like you discovered, just `$dirs` only returns the first item from the array.

To actually traverse these directories looking for a particular file, maybe try

```
desired_file_name=$1  # or whatever
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    test -e "$dir/$desired_file_name" || continue
    echo "$0: found $dir/$desired_file_name" >&2
done
```

Another approach is

```
find "${dirs[@]}" -name "$desired_file_name"
```

(You should prefer lower case for your private variables, so I changed `DIRS` to `dirs`. Less shouting is good for the eyes, too.)

Comment: Huh, I guess I didn't test what I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

To find a file named `$name` on your `PATH` using a bash loop:

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=:
for d in $PATH
do
    [ -f "$d/$name" ] && echo "Found $d/$name"
done
IFS=$oldIFS
```

On many systems, such as debian, `which` is just a shell script and it uses a very similar loop.  Have a look at `less /usr/bin/which`.